# QRCodeReaderView - Android: How to implement in fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am switching my use of QRCodeReaderView from Activity to Fragments and I am having problems. I moved the activity to the following fragment that is being called by a swipeview. 
Here is the code:

```
public class MainBusinessFragment extends Fragment implements QRCodeReaderView.OnQRCodeReadListener {
RoyalPoints points = new RoyalPoints();
private QRCodeReaderView mydecoderview;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View myView = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_main_business, container, false);
    mydecoderview = (QRCodeReaderView) myView.findViewById(R.id.qrdecoderview);
    mydecoderview.setOnQRCodeReadListener(this);
    return myView;
}

// Called when a QR is decoded
// "text" : the text encoded in QR
// "points" : points where QR control points are placed
@Override
public void onQRCodeRead(String text, PointF[] points) {
    final String user = text;
    ImageView clicker = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.clicker);
    clicker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    clicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addPoints(user);

                    }
                });

                }

                private void addPoints(String user) {
                    points.setPoints(10);
                    points.setUser(user);
                    points.setBusiness(ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
                    points.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "10 Points added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                }
```

I am having the following error and can't move forward ("java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ilias.royal.MainBusinessFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity"). 
Any help would be really appreciated, thank you.

Comment: When is this error thrown ? during "getActivity()" ? And is it a Fragment defined in XML or only by code ?

Comment: I cant seem to find it. I tried to replace getActivity() by getView() but it does not work either. Also, it does have an associated XML but not fragment-specific

Comment: where does the error throw exactly ? which line ? maybe it's not even in this class.

Comment: At which line exception is being thrown?

Comment: He doesnt know. Please had all your error stack trace

Comment: I can't use stacktrace. I can't manage to set it up without an emulator